# if-statement always evaluates to TRUE

Tags: linux, bash, unix, process

Is there any reason why this script always returns "running", regardless of whether my  process is started or stopped?

```
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "processName" > /dev/null
then
   echo $"running"
else
   echo $"not running"
fi
```

Thank you very much

**UPDATE :**
I add a full example of my script, maybe there is something wrong elsewhere.

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    # Start daemons.

    echo -n $"Starting daemon: "
    ;;

  stop)
    # Stop daemons.
    echo -n $"Shutting down: "
    echo
    ;;
  status)
    pgrep -f "ProcessName" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $"ProcessName is running"
    else
        echo $"ProcessName is not running"
    fi
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;

  *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    exit 1
esac
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
[user@dev init.d]# pgrep -f "MyProcess" > /dev/null
[user@dev init.d]# echo $?
0
[user@dev init.d]# service MyProcess stop
Shutting down MyProcess: Terminated
[user@dev init.d]# pgrep -f "MyProcess" > /dev/null
[user@dev init.d]# echo $?
1
```

But `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` seems to be TRUE all the time

Comment: To answer your question, yes there is. ;-)

Comment: @Mike, what do you see when you remove the output redirection to /dev/null?  Is your process, or something similarly named, in fact, running?

Comment: @pilcrow, When my process is started, I see the result of my process, when the process is stopped, I don't see any result.

Comment: @Mike, allow me to clarify:  what do you see from your if/grep/echo code -- the code you posted -- when the /dev/null redirection is removed?  Show us both when the process is "started" and when "stopped."  Do you see one or more lines of ps output?  (Maybe your process is SIGSTOP'd, maybe another one has a similar name, etc.)  Thanks.

Comment: @pilcrow, Started :  6628 pts/0    Sl     0:17 /opt/jrockit1.5.0_14/bin/java .....
Not Started : nothing

Comment: My guess is that the "pgrep -f ProcessName" is matching the name of you script, so every time you run your script it gives you a false positive.

Comment: Why is `command; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then X; else Y; fi` such a common idiom?  Use `if command; then X; else Y; fi`.

Also, why `echo $"foo"` instead of `echo "foo"`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ps aux | grep -q "[p]rocessName"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "not running"
fi
```

The brackets around the first letter of processName means do don't need the "grep -v grep", while the -q means we don't need the pipe to /dev/null

$? gives you the return code of the previous command executed. Hence, testing if it were 0 would indicate if "grep" found what it was looking for.

**Update**

If your process name is really short (say "cup"), you might get a false positive as it may match other processes too (say "cupsd"). You can overcome this by having grep match whole words - add the "-w" flag.

Not that this technique is not perfect. You may end up matching entries in the username/date fields. If that happens, look up "man ps" and be more selective of what you print out before doing a grep. Alternatively, prefilter the output with awk to extract only the column showing process/cmd name . E.g:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $11}' | grep -q -w "[p]rocessName"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "not running"
fi
```

**Update 2**

you can also use pgrep as suggested in answer below.

For really short process names, you might want to specify word boundaries (\b) before and after your process name to prevent overmatching (as described above)

```
pgrep "\bprocname\b" > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "not running"
fi
```

**Update 3**

From the updated question, I see that you're running it from an init script. There's always a danger of pgrep matching the script itself. Try:

```
pgrep Processname | grep -q -v $$
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "not running"
fi
```

That excludes the PID of the script from pgrep matches.

**Update 4**

(final update? fingers crossed)

If the init script is run via the "service" command, then we need to filter out the parent PID as well. How about:

```
pgrep Processname | grep -v $$ | grep -q -v $PPID
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "not running"
fi
```

Comment: Hey, that's actually a nifty trick with the [p]rocessname - +1 for proving old dogs can learn new tricks.

Comment: He should simply be able to 'if ps aux | grep -q "[p]rocessName"; then echo running; else echo not running; fi'  The extra test using [ is unnecessary.

Comment: @Mike: What process name are you grepping for. If it returned running all the time you tried, then it must be matching some other process name too (or usernames, or data, or any other output of 'ps aux').

Comment: @lsc: No when I run the command itself, nothing is returned when the process is stopped.

Comment: @Mike: answer updated with more info. Sorry, but I don't get what you mean by "nothing is returned when the process is stopped".

Comment: ok I think all your answers are good. but there's something wrong with my script. If I open a command line and I type pgrep -f "MyProcessName" there's is no result when the process is stopped. When I put this line in a if statement, it always returns running. It's very strange.

Comment: @Mike: answer update for case where your script has the same name as the process in question.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right about the problem, but the solution doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Quick experiment. Does it work if you call your script using "/etc/init.d/Processname status" instead of "service Processname status"??

Comment: Answer updated to include case where script is run via another comamnd/script.

Answer (score 2):

Probably becasue `grep "processName"` finds itself. I found this self same problem yesterday, except I was `xarg`ing the results to `kill`...

As an alternative you might like to try the `pgrep` command instead of your string of `ps` and various `grep`s:

```
sd@camel:~$ pgrep bash
415
3477
sd@camel:~$ echo $?
0
sd@camel:~$ pgrep arf
sd@camel:~$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: @Stephen, no, the OP excludes ps lines containing "grep" in the middle of his original pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

As an aside, instead of

```
ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "processName"
```

Try doing

```
ps ax | grep "[p]rocessName"
```

The ps is listing the grep function because it is seeing the string "grep processName" in the process list which is being passed by your grep for the string "processName".

Grepping for "[p]rocessName" will match just "processName" on its own, but not the string "grep [p]rocessName".

Comment: Good observation.  pgrep, or ``ps ax -o comm | grep -q -w commandName'', or any number of shellisms will do.  But these are comments on the OP's issue, not answers...

Answer (score -1):

your not doing a test.  put brackets around the test condition like so:

if [ condition your testing ]

Comment: Without [], the if tests the exit status of the command given, so his script is (in the correct spirit) trying to test the exit of grep.

Comment: @Emil yes effectively not testing the condition he wants!!  In fact if anyAccessibleCommand without brackets returns true

Comment: The OP's problem is that grep returned true when it found itself, not the use of if.

Comment: @Emil I didn't say he shouldn't use the if just that using [] syntactically does what his semantics require!!